# Quad Core but Single Core on task manager

Tags: multi-core, central-processing-unit, acpi

ACPI Multiprocessor -> Check
4 Processor shown on Device  Manager -> Check
4 Processor shown on Task Manager -> Nope

OS -> Windows 2003 Enterprise 32Bit

[image: screencap]

Should I see four processers on the Task Manager, and if so how can I get them visible?

Comment: Yes, check the `View` and Graphs and select the way you want to show them.

Answer (score 1):

From Task Manager, select View... CPU History... One Graph Per CPU.

Comment: It is already "One Graph per CPU". Actually there's only "One Graph Per CPU" on the "CPU History" menu.

Comment: Is this a virtual server server that was converted from a physical server? If so, did you change from multiple pCPU's to a single vCPU or vice versa? If going from a single pCPU to a multiple vCPU Windows will automatically upgrade the HAL to Multiprocessor but it can't go the other way (not automatically anyway). If any of these scenarios are the case then that might explain why you're seeing what you're seeing.

Comment: Yes, the original was physical machine (2 physical CPU with single core each), the original has ACPI MULTIPROCESSOR. The new machine is virtual with 4 vCPU and also ACPI MULTIPROCESSOR (so, no HAL change). The hypervisor is Citrix Xenserver 5.6. I've had successful conversions before, but this one got me baffled :(

Comment: The virtual machine part probably should be in the original question.  If you don't give the environment, kind of hard to help. Feel free to visit that edit link.